# cannot use the pip command on termux ubunty , says OSError , cant fint path to android path folder

Tags: python-3.x, pip, termux, oserror

When i tried to use the pip command on ubuntu , on termux it says , no module named jnia
which pip returns **/usr/bin/pip**
how can I make the pip command usable ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/platformdirs/android.py", line 85, in _android_folder                                                  from jnius import autoclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jnius'      
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main                                                  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>           from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>            from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 39, in <module>               from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .base import get_major_minor_version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    USER_CACHE_DIR = appdirs.user_cache_dir("pip")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 17, in user_cache_dir
    return _appdirs.user_cache_dir(appname, appauthor=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/platformdirs/__init__.py", line 114, in user_cache_dir
    return PlatformDirs(appname=appname, appauthor=appauthor, version=version, opinion=opinion).user_cache_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/platformdirs/android.py", line 43, in user_cache_dir                                                   return self._append_app_name_and_version(_android_folder(), "cache")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/platformdirs/android.py", line 97, in _android_folder                                                  raise OSError("Cannot find path to android app folder")                                         OSError: Cannot find path to android app folder
```

Answer (score 3):

Do `ANDROID_DATA=anything`, so pip will think it is running in a normal linux not android.

[image: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/platformdirs/init.py]

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pip install <package>`.